# Increase badness based on distance between float and reference

Tags: floats, positioning

One thing I really often struggle with when writing a latex document (and I belive a lot of people are in the same case) is float placement.

In particular, I often find myself with a figure or table located several pages away from the place where ther were referenced.

As I understand it, the way latex choses where to put a float is by trying to minimize the "badness", which is a numeric value used to characterize how bad a certain placement would be.

And in this regard, I think we can agree that placing a figure several pages away from the place where it is needed is pretty bad.

Therefore, is there a way to increase the badness of this when I need to do so ?

To be more specific, I see two possible kinds of badness :

- the vertical distance between the paragraph where it is referenced and the float
- The presence of page breaks between these two.

Alternatively, how could it be implemented, or even, would this be the right way to approach this problem ?

Comment: First, try to understand why a float is sent several pages away. May be you are forcing this. Adding more options to the float could solve the problem. In other case, relax the LaTeX rules. See http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/GF/bibliog/latex/floats.html.

Comment: Throwing in an occasional \vfil helps.